# Ionic 2 - scroll event not fired when finger is off the screen

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2

I have an Ionic app with a header that I want to resize based on scrollTop. I'm using Ionic's scroll event on IonScroll :

```
import { Scroll } from 'ionic-angular';  

@ViewChild(Scroll) scroll: Scroll;

...

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.scroll.addScrollEventListener((ev) => {
        console.log('scroll');
    });
}
```

On iOS, the scroll event is fired perfectly when I keep my finger on the screen, but when the finger is off the screen (but the scrolling continues because of the inertia), the event is only fired when the scrolling stops.

Is there a way to listen to the scroll event (or any other similar event) when the finger is off the screen ?

I found this question, which seems similar but doesn't have any answer: [iOS scroll event not firing as often when finger is off of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356388/ios-scroll-event-not-firing-as-often-when-finger-is-off-of-the-screen)

Comment: You can try `touchmove` `touchstart` `touchend` event

Comment: What I want is to listen to the scroll when the finger is not touching the screen (i.e. when the content is still scrolling because of the scroll momentum on iOS), I believe that `touchstart`, `touchend`and `touchmove` are only fired when the finger is on the screen...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of months ago I had a similar issue (in my case I wanted to show/hide a "scrollToTop" button when scrolling down a list. It would work fine when the finger was on screen, but not if you let it go.

The bottom line is that the UIWebView has some limitations regarding scrolling and scroll-detection seems to be one of those issues. See: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10630

The solution that the Ionic-Team suggests is using WKWebView instead because these issues don't exist there.

https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

One last thing you can try, although I'm pretty sure it won't make a difference in your case, is running your code in an NgZone:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

export class myPage {
  zone: NgZone;

  constructor() {
    this.zone = new NgZone({enableLongStackTrace: false});

    this.content.ionScroll.subscribe(($event) => {
       this.zone.run(() => {
           // console.log($event);
       });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I had never heard of the WKWebView solution, it just solved my issue. Thank you!