# Ionic3 ionScroll not firing properly in iOS

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

While this is working perfectly in Android, it seems that in iOS stops getting the scroll event when the finger is removed from the screen, even tho it is still scrolling due to the acceleration of the scroll.

```
 this.content.ionScroll.subscribe((data) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            console.log(data.scrollTop);
        });
    });
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Is there a better way to capture the scroll events?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to scrolling/scroll detection limitations in UiWebView and cannot be fixed.

The only "solution" is to use the WkWebView instead because the issues don't exist there. But beware if you use this in an already existing app. This will replace the WebView of your app and I read that the LocalStorage might be replaced (maybe they implemented a migration now). So use it with caution.

https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Comment: I answered a similar question a couple of weeks ago. You can check it for a more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820109/ionic-2-scroll-event-not-fired-when-finger-is-off-the-screen/44823811